# Android crashes when sends string

Tags: java, android

I want to send a string from a numeric `EditText` from one activity to another. But when I click save my apk crashes. Here is the code and logcat.

Settings

```
public class settings extends Activity {

    Button btnSave;
    TextView text;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

        btnSave = (Button)findViewById(R.id.save);
        final EditText passkey = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);


        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String pass = passkey.getText().toString();

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(settings.this, unlock.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("String", pass);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Unlock

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_unlock);

        String newString;
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            if(extras == null) {
                newString= null;
            } else {
                newString= extras.getString("String");
            }
        } else {
            newString= (String) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("String");
        }
```

onResume() method.

```
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        address = intent.getStringExtra(DeviceList.EXTRA_ADDRESS);

        BluetoothDevice device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);

        try {
            btSocket = createBluetoothSocket(device);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Socket creation failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        try
        {
            btSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            try
            {
                btSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e2)
            {
                //
            }
        }
        mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(btSocket);
        mConnectedThread.start();

        mConnectedThread.write("x");
    }
```

Device list

```
public class DeviceList extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnPaired;
    ListView devicelist;
    private BluetoothAdapter myBluetooth = null;
    private Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices;
    public static String EXTRA_ADDRESS = "device_address";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_device_list);

        btnPaired = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        devicelist = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

        myBluetooth = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if(myBluetooth == null)
        {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth Device Not Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            finish();
        }
        else
        {
            if (myBluetooth.isEnabled())
            { }
            else
            {

                Intent turnBTon = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(turnBTon,1);
            }
        }
        btnPaired.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                pairedDevicesList();
            }
        });
    }

    private void pairedDevicesList()
    {
        pairedDevices = myBluetooth.getBondedDevices();
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

        if (pairedDevices.size()>0)
        {
            for(BluetoothDevice bt : pairedDevices)
            {
                list.add(bt.getName() + "\n" + bt.getAddress());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Paired Bluetooth Devices Found.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
        devicelist.setAdapter(adapter);
        devicelist.setOnItemClickListener(myListClickListener);
    }
    private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener myListClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        public void onItemClick (AdapterView av, View v, int arg2, long arg3)
        {
            String info = ((TextView) v).getText().toString();
            String address = info.substring(info.length() - 17);

            Intent i = new Intent(DeviceList.this, unlock.class);

            i.putExtra(EXTRA_ADDRESS, address);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    };

}
```

Comment: show your `onResume()`?

Comment: i posted it, i hope it helps

Comment: what are you doing in onResume();

Comment: it's for the bluetooth, I do everything in onCreate

Comment: in activity unlock I have btn Settings, when I press it, it opens a new activity where i need put passkey in edittext, when I press save btn, it should send this passkey to unlock activity, but when I press it, apk crashes

Comment: `address = intent.getStringExtra(DeviceList.EXTRA_ADDRESS);` you are recive value from which class?

Comment: I have 3 activities, 4 but one is loading screen and don't count it, one is device list which finds arduino bluetooth device and connects to it and then opens unlock activity

Comment: what is `DeviceList.EXTRA_ADDRESS` value?

Comment: it's device adress

Comment: ok then how you are passing device address in intent? this is the same address you are passing in bye typing in edittext?

Comment: i have the same adress in device list and in unlock, do i have to do the same cpy/pst to settings activity too?

Comment: you didt provide full info cant fig out your issue?

Comment: i'll just post all 3 activites, I think it'll be easier to understand

Comment: I added device list and settings, unlock is almost whole here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now what is happening you are opening `Single class` from `two positions` with `different values` one with `device address` and one with `edit text` value.

so when you pass editext value device address is null and your app crash to handle this add validations.  `if(address != null)` then connect otherwise not.

```
   @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        address = intent.getStringExtra(DeviceList.EXTRA_ADDRESS);

      if(address != null){
        BluetoothDevice device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);

        try {
            btSocket = createBluetoothSocket(device);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Socket creation failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        try
        {
            btSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            try
            {
                btSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e2)
            {
            }
        }
        mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(btSocket);
        mConnectedThread.start();
        mConnectedThread.write("x");
    }
}
```

Comment: @H.Stefek you are welcome next provide full info.happy coding

Comment: now, when I return from settings to unlock, whatever button I press, it crashes

Answer (score 0):

In `onResume()` you are doing

```
Intent intent = getIntent();

        address = intent.getStringExtra(DeviceList.EXTRA_ADDRESS);

        BluetoothDevice device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
```

when did you pass anything from intent having key `DeviceList.EXTRA_ADDRESS`  and here is the problem. After that you are finding remoteDevice by that null address.

Comment: I have 3 activities, 4 but one is loading screen and don't count it, one is device list which finds arduino bluetooth device and connects to it and then opens unlock activity

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null is not a valid Bluetooth address.

Comment: the error is above one and you will always find exact error inside the log with the keyword 'Caused by:'. The main cause of error will always find by this keyword.

Comment: You can even trace error inside your app to know which line is causing error  by using app in debug mode

Comment: @Aditi you are right but it not answer to question.

Comment: explain what do you want from Bluetooth device then only i will be able to help you